# how can I find out deployment date?

Tags: cisco, dell, aruba, huawei

How can I find out what date the switch is` deployed first time or any closer date or anything that I can estimate? Consider the switch is huwaei/dell/cisco/aruba.

Thanks

Comment: (Mandatory legal statement - I work for Dell). This is probably answerable but I would have to know what you mean by deploy because that means different things to each customer I work with. Turned on for the first time? Configured? Configured and then put in an active environment?

Answer (score 3):

Usually you'd have that date in your inventory.

For HPE/Aruba gear you can use the warranty check (requires registration as of late): https://support.hpe.com/connect/s/?card=wc.

Cisco: https://connectthedots.cisco.com/connectdots/serviceWarrantyFinderRequest

Dell: https://www.dell.com/support/contents/en-us/Category/Warranty

Huawei: https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/warranty

Feature licenses might tell you when they were activated but often only show how long they're valid.

Other than tools like that you're likely condemned to digging up invoices...

Comment: I am looking for some clue on the device itself. mostly licence of those devices expired.

Comment: @hakkican, the closest you can come from the device itself is the last time it was reloaded, and that could be much more recent than it was deployed. It sounds like your business is not using industry-standard practices. You should have a data store with that type of information. Also, you really need to have much more current code running on your devices for security reasons to fix vulnerabilities.

Comment: I checked on uptime history. I m not a boss and do not own this business . It is a temp job and I hope to get this business to comply with industry-standard practices. thanks

Comment: You cannot force a company to comply with anything you want if you are in a temporary position, unless it is a temporary position as owner, CEO, etc. 

Even mentioning that you investigated that kind of information might lead to your termination unless that is the specific role you were hired for. If it is the role you were hired for, it seems strange because you should already be familiar with the fact that network equipment doesn't store that kind of information. It might have a sticker with date of manufacture and data on last boot up time at best.

Answer (score 0):

For enterprise grade hardware, the best bet is to find the date of manufacture sticker on the chassis. Beyond that, you'd have to have your own history database, or find it in the vendor's database. I don't know of any hardware that keeps any sort of "warrantee" activation date in NVRAM. (consumer devices, sure, and they're dirt simple to reset.)

If the firmware has never been updated (and how would you know that?), maybe the flash filesystem has a date?

Comment: I just picked huawei. https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1100088100 . I think this is the sticker you are talking about ? I do not think this stick could have such a deployment date on the label. How could I have my won database ? Do you mean shipping logs to other location? How can I find it in the vendor's database?  I can see the update operation date but this just helps me narrow down the  date. Thanks